# Get all combinations of List<string> where order doesn't matter and minimum of 2 elements with C#

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation

I've reviewed all StackOverflow posts on combinations and permutations, and can't find the exact nuanced answer I'm looking for, nor can I wrap my head around how to correctly implement this.  Ideally I'm looking for a solution that does not use recursion, so I can avoid a stack overflow on big lists.  How do I get all combinations of a list of strings, with the following requirements?

- Minimum of 2 elements in each resultant list
- Order doesn't matter for equality.  In other words, ("a", "b") == ("b", "a")

Example:

```
var input = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };

// TODO


// Note: the final order of lists in expectedResult doesn't matter
var expectedResult = new List<List<string>>{
    new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" },
    new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" },
    new List<string> { "a", "b", "d" },
    new List<string> { "a", "c", "d" },
    new List<string> { "b", "c", "d" },
    new List<string> { "a", "b" },
    new List<string> { "a", "c", },
    new List<string> { "a", "d" },
    new List<string> { "b", "c" },
    new List<string> { "b", "d" },
    new List<string> { "c", "d" }
};

Assert.IsTrue(expectedResult.Count == 11);
Assert.IsTrue(expectedResult.All(list => list.Count >= 2));
```

Comment: Like a betting round robin?

Comment: "Order doesn't matter for equality" - meaning that if you produce `{ "a", "b" }` then you **don't** want to product `{ "b", "a" }`?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro I'm not familiar with that analogy... hopefully the asserts above define the solution.

Comment: @Enigmativity - yes, correct

Comment: @BlueSky - Sounds more like a simile rather than an analogy... :-)

Comment: @Enigmativity I think analogy is correct. simile="make a description more emphatic or vivid", analogy="a comparison between two things, typically for the purpose of explanation or clarification"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with a *numeric mask* to keep track of what you have visited and some *bit shifting*.

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetCombinations<T>(List<T> source)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < (1 << source.Count); i++)
      yield return source
         .Where((t, j) => (i & (1 << j)) != 0)
         .ToArray();
}
```

Or if you have *for loop OCD* and like extension methods

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> GetCombinations<T>(this List<T> source)
   => Enumerable
      .Range(0, 1 << source.Count)
      .Select(i => source
         .Where((t, j) => (i & (1 << j)) != 0)
         .ToArray());
```

**Usage**

```
var input = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

var results = GetCombinations(input)
      .Where(x => x.Length >= 2);

foreach (var items in results)
   Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",items));
```

**Output**

```
a,b
a,c
b,c
a,b,c
a,d
b,d
a,b,d
c,d
a,c,d
b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

Add pepper salt, and sort to taste

---

The premise is,

1. Using a *bitmask* for the combinations you want to return. Each *bit* represent a `true` or `false` and correlates to an element in the collection. I.e mask `1100` would mean return combination `C,D` etc.
2. Use a *loop* with a range of `Math.Pow(2, source.Count)` (or even better as [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity) suggested `1 << source.Count`) max combinations for a given set to increment the *mask*..
3. Then just put it all in an *iterator method* for a barrel of laughs... All combinations will be given.

The only limitation is the max size of the array is limited to *max bits* of the *numeric type* you can *bitshift* (in the current implementation) i.e. 32/64 elements depending on `int` or `long`, which will produce `2^32` / `2^64` combinations respectively.

**Updated**

Further comment by [Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity) (and something I wasn't aware of)

> You can use `BigInteger` to get around the max bits limit
>
> ```
> BigInteger one = 1; 
>
> for (BigInteger i = 0; i < one << source.Count; i++) 
>    yield return source.Where((_, j) => (i & one << j) != 0).ToArray();
> ```

Comment: May I suggest avoiding `Math.Pow(2, source.Count)` because it computes with `double` and simply use `1 << source.Count` instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity great suggestion, updated and attributed

Comment: You can use `BigInteger` to get around the max bits limit - `BigInteger one = 1; for (BigInteger i = 0; i < one << source.Count; i++) yield return source.Where((_, j) => (i & one << j) != 0).ToArray();`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks again. I wasn't are you could bitshift a` BigInteger`. Good to know!

Comment: Yep, I had to look it up myself - `public static BigInteger operator <<(BigInteger value, int shift)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacky solution to the problem:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GetPermutations(IList<string> input)
{
    List<List<string>> output = new List<List<string>>();

    for (int count = input.Count; count >= 2; count--)
    {
        var indexes = new int[count];

        // Set initial index values to be default (i.e. 0,1,2,3)
        for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
        {
            indexes[index] = index;
        }

        // Start at the last index (i.e. D) and build output
        for (int arrayIndex = indexes.Length - 1; arrayIndex >= 0; arrayIndex--)
        {
            bool indexCanBeIncremented = true;
            while (indexCanBeIncremented)
            {
                List<string> currentList = new List<string>();

                foreach (var index in indexes)
                {
                    currentList.Add(input[index]);
                }

                if (IsUnique(output, currentList))
                {
                    output.Add(currentList);
                }                       

                if (arrayIndex == indexes.Length - 1 && indexes[arrayIndex] < input.Count - 1 || 
                    arrayIndex < indexes.Length - 1 && indexes[arrayIndex] + 1 != indexes[arrayIndex + 1])
                {
                    indexes[arrayIndex] += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    indexCanBeIncremented = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}

public static bool IsUnique(List<List<string>> collection, List<string> input)
{
    foreach (var list in collection)
    {
        if (input.SequenceEqual(list))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code essentially keeps track of all the indexes of the input and will build the output up based on the permutations.

**Output**

```
a b c d
a b c
a b d
a c d
b c d
a b
a c
a d
b d
c d
```